# Best way to connect Flask and ElectronJS

Tags: flask, electron

I have developed a Flask app and GUI in electronJS. I can package it for windows and want to distribute it. I thought a good practice would be for Flask to first check for a free port when being launched and then export the value of that port to a json file. Electron waits for that file to be available and then connects to Flask via the correct port. The intention is to avoid bugs with users whose localhost and port would be already used if my port was set to a fix value (say 5000 for instance).

Is my method the best way to deal with the risk that Flask would run on a busy port if distributed to some users? Is there a smarter way to go around this issue?

Many thanks,
Nick

Comment: Assigning a port higher than 10000  for Flask  should be safe enough in this case, but creating a fall back might be necessary. You could create a list of ports as an array and loop through it, check if the port is currently used or not. If not, open the Flask app on that port. You could also expose a config file that allows the end user to change the port when necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Good point and simpler to deal with